# Java: Methods; Where am i doing it wrong?

Tags: java

I am studying Methods. I could have figure it out if i was not using Methods but I am trying to convert char to hex ASCII string by using Methods in Java.

I am getting error of `hexText` var is not been initialized.
Could you please point it out where is the problem?
Thank you for all your help.

Here is my code:

```
    package charToHex;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class charToHex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text, hexStr;

    System.out.print("Enter some text: ");
    text = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Hex value");
    hexText = hexStr(text);
    System.out.println(hexText);
    }

    public static String hexStr(String text)
            {
                // You need to implement this function
                char chr;
                int ASCII;
                String hexText;
                for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
                   character = text.charAt(i);
                   ASCII = (int)chr;
                   hexText = Integer.toHexString(ASCII);

                 }

    return hexText;
    }

    RUN:
    Enter some text: hi

        Exception in thread "main" hextStr message
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The local variable hexText may not have been initialized

    at charToHex.charToHex.hexStr(charToHex.java:80)
    at charToHex.charToHex.main(charToHex.java:30)
```

Comment: It is showing compilation error? Which IDE are you using? Just put the closing } at the end.

Comment: I - as begginer - also once thought that the text in an exception is here just to scare you.

Comment: @lacraig2 Yes, i missed copy however it was not the problem i was getting. I edited my question. thank you

Comment: @MouseEvent you are right :) But i just missed copy my code and missed a } however it was not the error i was getting. thank you

Comment: @hichris123 I am getting error of hexText var has not been initialized.

Comment: You have a compiler error because character is undefined...

Comment: In the `hexStr` method, change your declaration of the `hexText` variable from `String hexText;` to `String hexText = null;`  The problem is that the only other place you assign to that variable is inside the `for` loop, and the compiler isn't smart enough to know for sure that the code inside the loop will be executed (which is why the error says "may" not be initialized).

Comment: @user257427: I edited it and it should answer your question.

Comment: @jas thank you for your point. I've tried your solution before but i was getting hex value of the text and also "NULL" text at the end of the hex value. For exp: 6768NULL :(

Comment: Aha, okay, then much better to initialize to `""` as in lacrag2's solution. Glad it got worked out --- good luck with your program :-)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You need to declare hexText as a String in main. You need to declare character as a char in hexStr(String).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class charToText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text, hexStr;

        System.out.print("Enter some text: ");
        text = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Hex value");
        String hexText = hexStr(text);
        System.out.println(hexText);
    }

    public static String hexStr(String text) {
        // You need to implement this function
        char chr;
        int ASCII;
        String hexText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            chr = text.charAt(i);
            ASCII = (int) chr;
            hexText += Integer.toHexString(ASCII);

        }

        return hexText;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. TLDR:

```
hexText+= Integer.toHexString(ASCII);
```

Comment: Thank you for point it out. I realized that i missed copy the code. I edited my code.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I edited my code at my question and wrote the correct error that i was getting. Sorry again. thank you

Comment: Miss copying the code and answering the question are two separate issues

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you for your point. I corrected my code and wrote the correct error i was getting. Could you please take a look and help? Thank you

Comment: @user257427 try the code I have posted. It works for me. You will need to import java.util.Scanner;

Comment: @lacraig2 I really appreciated all your help unlike some others. However i am not getting the correct hex value of the input.

Comment: @user257427 have you tried hexText += Integer.toHexString(ASCII);. You seem to be discarding the value each time as opposed to adding it. Is this shat you are looking for?

Comment: @lacraig2 Thank you very much. MY PROBLEM IS SOLVED. UPVOTE+++++ for you. You are the expert :) (Sorry for caps)